# Docker Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the Sitecore 10.2 project in Docker.

I ran `.\init`, After that I ran `.\build -topology xp1 -buildConfiguration debug`
Then ran .\up -topology xp1 so while I am running `.\up -topology xp1` I am getting the below error:

[image]

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30213/jss-containers-setup-cm-container-does-not-start-or-attempt-to-start

Comment: Where is the scale setting need to do?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/build-sitecore-solutions.html

Comment: @SwatiGupta hope this issue related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970654/win10-docker-build-invoke-webrequest-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server

Comment: Make sure you have **stopped IIS**. Try stopping the IIS, open Docker Desktop and run the commands again.